# PHPUnit testing cli script

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit

I have a cli script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
if (!isset($argv[1])) die("Usage: $argv[0] <config.xml> [InputPrefix1 ... InputPrefixN]\n");
class MyClass {
    //etc..
}
```

How do I write a phpunit tests for this script?

When I try to bootstrap the file for testing, I get a "undefined variable: argv" error.

> phpunit --bootstrap ./my-cli-script ./tests

Comment: Try re-loading your $argv variable: `$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];`

Comment: try define it in the test case

Comment: Do you really want to test the cli-script or the class defined below? Maybe you should make the classes independent from the cli environment and test them in isolation.